# Gitlab very slow on Ubuntu 16.04LTS Server

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, gitlab

I've got Gitlab (Omnibus) installed on an Ubuntu 16.04LTS box with all the latest updates etc as of today and whatever the latest Gitlab version is. It's a VMWare virtual machine with 4GB RAM and 2 cores.

My Gitlab installation has only two users and about 10 projects. It's literally just me using it at the moment though. Pushing/pulling via `git` commands is fine but the web-ui is very slow. It can take 20 seconds or so to load a page. Tried various browsers, no change. This is really poor performance given that it's on the local network.

`htop` is showing anywhere from 3-3.8gb of RAM in use, while the CPUs appear pretty much idle, only spiking a small amount if I try to load a page. I don't really care what the memory usage is as long as the page loading time improves. This server is not used for anything else at all.

I've tried tweaking some configuration file options but the performance has not improved.

```
Settings in: /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

postgresql['shared_buffers'] = "1024MB"
prometheus_monitoring['enable'] = false
```

Everything else is default. What other settings should I be amending to improve the performance of Gitlab, without having to throw more resources at the box? I can provide more information if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the antivirus I'd installed was using all the resources up. Removed `clamAV` and Gitlab is really fast again.